# Fuse.js constructor issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, fuse.js

Im trying to add a fuzzy search library to my project via fuse.js. I include the following lines and I'm getting a constructor error, I tried to re-install fuse but I'm wondering where the error may be.

```
// TypeError: Fuse is not a constructor

var Fuse = require('fuse');

var options = { // list of options that need to be provided to fuse.js for search to occur
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.6,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 1,
  keys: [
    "title", // the keys that are searched
    "description"
  ]
};

var fuse = new Fuse(posts, options); // "list" is the item array
var result = fuse.search(searchOptions.keywords); // search is conducted and result should be all matching JSON objects
```

Answer (score 7):

You're confusing the [**fuse.js**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuse.js) module with the [**fuse**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuse) module, which is a [completely different project](https://github.com/smebberson/fuse). You can see that this is the case by looking at the ["Install"](http://fusejs.io/#install) section of the Fuse.js website.

To fix this, run `npm install --save fuse.js` and fix line with the require to this:

```
var Fuse = require('fuse.js');
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using typescript?

You need to first install the library: run `npm install --save fuse.js`.

Then import the library on top of the file that you are going to use the library:
`import * as Fuse from 'fuse.js'`